# Selenium Simple Issue

Tags: python, selenium

> My problem is that, Firefox opens perfectly with the desired profile
> but won't loads the url mentioned below

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver
options = Options()
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument('/home/123/.mozilla/firefox/user123.default')
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

It Just shows the homepage :(

Does anyone know how to solve this Issue ?

Comment: What version of selenium are you using? I tried with `selenium-4.0.0` and it worked for me. Just used `options` instead of `firefox_options` in second-last line.

Comment: @akhilsp I'm using Selenium 3.141.0 and firefox 94.0

Comment: I'm not getting the output by changing the `firefox_options` to `options`